sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 2: type 'list' is not supported
При попытки использования pandas.DataFrame.to_sql отображается ошибка sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 2: type 'list' is not supported. Код:
def saveChanges(x = 1):
    curs.execute(f"DROP TABLE {tableNameVar}_{grade}_{schoolname}")

    global studentsTableList, marksTableList
    students = []

    for i in range(len(students2)):
        for y in range(len(students2[i])):
            students.append(students2[i][y])
    students = tuple(students)
    print(students)

    marksTableList = []
    marksTableList.append(marksTable.get())

    mtl_tuple = []

    for x in range(len(marksTableList[0])):
        mtl_tuple.append((tuple(marksTableList[0][x])))
    mtl_tuple = tuple(mtl_tuple)
    print(mtl_tuple)

    table = []
    table.append(students)
    table.append(marksTableList)

    tosql = pd.DataFrame(tuple(table))
    tosql.to_sql(f"{tableNameVar}_{grade}_{schoolname}", conn)

Переменные:
tableNameVar - текст, который берется из tk.Entry
curs - курсор sqlite3.cursor
conn - коннектор sqlite3.connect
students2 - список с учениками, берётся из БД
marksTable - таблица CTkTable
grade и schoolname - класс и название школы

Ну вы хотя бы посмотрели, что у вас за датафрейм сформировался? Выглядит вообще излишне переусложнённым его создание.
